# Compute and compare the average of two columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I started converting my Pandas implementations to pySpark but i'm having trouble going through some basic operations. So I have this table:

```
+-----+-----+----+
| Col1|Col2 |Col3|
+-----+-----+----+
|  1  |[1,3]|   0|
|  44 |[2,0]|   1|
|  77 |[1,5]|   7|
+-----+-----+----+
```

My desired output is:

```
+-----+-----+----+----+
| Col1|Col2 |Col3|Col4|
+-----+-----+----+----+
|  1  |[1,3]|   0|2.67|
|  44 |[2,0]|   1|2.67|
|  77 |[1,5]|   7|2.67|
+-----+-----+----+----+
```

To get here :

- I averaged the first item of every array in Col2 and averaged the second item of every array in Col2. Since the average of the second "sub-column" is bigger  ((3+0+5)/3) than the first "sub-column" ((1+2+1)/3) this is the "winning" condition. After that I created a new column that has the "winning" average replicated over the number of rows of that table (in this example 3).
  I was already able to do this by "manually" selecting ta column, average it and then use a "lit" to replicate the results. The problem with my implementation is that collect() takes a lot of time and afaik its not recommended.
  Could you please help me on this one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `greatest` to get the greatest average of each (sub-)column in the array:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'Col4',
    F.greatest(*[F.avg(F.udf(lambda r: [float(i) for i in r.toArray()], 'array<double>')('Col2')[i]).over(Window.orderBy()) for i in range(2)])
)

df2.show()
+----+------+----+------------------+
|Col1|  Col2|Col3|              Col4|
+----+------+----+------------------+
|   1|[1, 3]|   0|2.6666666666666665|
|  44|[2, 0]|   1|2.6666666666666665|
|  77|[1, 5]|   7|2.6666666666666665|
+----+------+----+------------------+
```

If you want the array size to be dynamic, you can do

```
arr_size = df.select(F.max(F.size(F.udf(lambda r: [float(i) for i in r.toArray()], 'array<double>')('Col2')))).head()[0]

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'Col4',
    F.greatest(*[F.avg(F.udf(lambda r: [float(i) for i in r.toArray()], 'array<double>')('Col2')[i]).over(Window.orderBy()) for i in range(arr_size)])
)
```

Comment: That looks like it should work but I'm getting an error. This table is generated when i do model.transform (from a Random Forest model) . PS: the "probability" column is the "Col2" on this example:  Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o43620.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from probability#36630: need struct type but got struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>;

Comment: @DiogoRibeiro oh, I didn't realize that was a vector column. Then you can use `vector_to_array` to convert to array type first - see edited answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I forgot to add that I'm running spark 2.4 which doest not have vector_to_array.

Comment: @DiogoRibeiro added a udf solution